# On Exchange plans mixed in with Off Exchange plans

Tags: data-request

I ran individual quote from finder.healthcare.gov (zip: 23513, dob: 02/03/1982, Male, No-Tobacco) and the results are showing On Exchange plans mixed in with Off exchange plans (E.g. Anthem HealthKeepers Bronze X 4900 for HSA - is On Market plan, and Anthem HealthKeepers Bronze 4900 for HSA - is Off Market plan). How do I tell which plan is On Exchange, which plan is Off Exchange? I thought finder.healthcare.gov is supposed to show only Off Exchange plans.